# Beginner having trouble with return value - JAVA

Tags: java, math, geometry

I am failing to get an answer (volume of a cube)

It keeps returning `0.0` as an answer and I could not figure out what I am doing wrong. Why isn't the `volume()` method actually multiplying the `cubeSide`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 class Cube{

    private double cubeSide;
    private double volumeAnswer;

    //default const
    public Cube(){
        cubeSide = 0;
    }
    //argument constructor
    public Cube(double inp){
        cubeSide = inp;
    }

    //method for volume
    public void volume(){
        volumeAnswer = cubeSide * cubeSide * cubeSide;

    }

    //returning value
    public double returnIt(){
        return volumeAnswer;
    }


}//end of class cube




public class myCubeClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        /*
            Cube class 
               - Two constructors (one default and the other with length argument)
               - A method called "Volume"
               - A Method called getVolume

        */

             //create new cube object 
            Cube cube1 = new Cube(3.23);  

             System.out.println("Ans: " + cube1.returnIt());



    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

Comment: You aren't calling `volume()` anywhere in your code.... consider making it a part of the constructor

Answer (score 6):

The method `volume` that performs the calculation is never called. Better to return the result from the method itself to avoid this type of logical error

```
public double getVolume() {
    return cubeSide * cubeSide * cubeSide;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

volumeAnswer hasn't been set to anything yet.

Call cube1.volume() first